# The output has extra % sign in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

```
int n,t;
cin>>n>>t;
char arr[n];
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    cin>>arr[i];
}
// for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
//     cout<<arr[i];
// }
while(t>0){
    for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++){
        if((arr[i]=='B')&&(arr[i+1]=='G')){
            char temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[i+1];
            arr[i+1] = arr[i];
            i++;
        }
    }
    --t;
}
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
}
```

I am getting one extra % sign while printing the output
Like if input is BGGBG
output is appearing as GGBGB%

Comment: Use the debugger.

Comment: I tried to setup dubugger in code OSS but it never works. I use Arch Linux .

Comment: Before main finishes, add `cout << "\n--- done ---\n";`

Comment: @Dexter without debugging you will get nowhere. Install a proper IDE to a proper OS.

Comment: Not related to your issue, but note that variable length arrays, i.e. `int n; cin >> n; char a[n];` is *not* standard c++. Prefer `vector` instead.

Comment: Variable length arrays [are not valid C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1887097/6865932), use `std::vector`, or in this case, more appropriately `std::string`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/5910058

Comment: gdb doesn't work so I will try to find alternative debuggers.

Comment: @Dexter `gdb` is a fine debugger and works well. Either your system is broken or you are using it wrong.

Comment: I get this error   Unable to open 'basic_file.cc': Unable to read file '/build/gcc/src/gcc-build/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/src/c++98/basic_file.cc' (Error: Unable to resolve non-existing file '/build/gcc/src/gcc-build/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/src/c++98/basic_file.cc')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extra "%" is not something printed by your program. It is just something that your shell added to tell you that there is no newline character after the text.

In order to easily check this you can redirect your program output to a file. You will see that the "%" character will not be in the file.

Alternatively, if you print a newline at the end of your program you will not see the "%" character in your shell.

Comment: Thanks! Yesterday I changed my shell that's why it is happening.

Comment: I'm glad to help. If it fully answers your question you should accept the answer.